# keeping track of allocated sizes if using std::allocator

Tags: c++11, memory-management

If we use `std::allocator` in  `myVector<T, std::allocator<T> >` (reimplementation of `std::vector`)  and have some expanding function 
like

```
 inline void expand(std::size_t e){
        // expand capacity by e elements
        T * p = m_allocator.allocate(e);
        ...
        store pointers [p, p+e] internally
        ...
 }
```

`m_allocator` is the internal instance of `std::allocator<T>`.

if we then delete an instance of `myVector`, we obviously delete all
pointers [p,p+e] through the allocator by (pseudo loop)

```
for p in [p,p+e]:
  m_allocator.destroy(p)

m_allocator.deallocate(p,e)
```

Because std::allocator wants the same arguments in the deallocate function as used in the allocation function, we need to store the number `e` somewhere internally. Can this be avoided, by doing something like:

```
for p in [p,p+e]:
      m_allocator.destroy(p)
      m_allocator.deallocate(p,1)
```

Comment: Why don't you have that number? Isn't that just the capacity?

Comment: i dont know, because we might have called `expand` several times before deconstructing the myVector instance,